# Как улучшить код по получению непустого элемента из массива?

Tags: php

Вводные: есть некий массив с ключами, есть строка с несколькими ключами, один из которых подойдет к этому массиву (т.е. элемент с таким ключом будет существовать).

**Задача минимум:** наиболее красиво получить значение первого элемента массива, ключ которого подойдет.

**Задача максимум:** наиболее красиво получить значение первого элемента массива, ключ которого подойдет, а если подойдут несколько ключей, выдать ошибку.

**Задача сверх максимума:** наиболее красиво получить значение первого элемента массива, ключ которого подойдет, а если подойдут несколько ключей, выдать ошибку. При этом, если ключ передан как `fields[name_1]`, нужно понять, что **имеется ввиду вложенность в элемент** и обработать очередной элемент массива в соответствии с этим.

На данный момент реализована задача минимум, но без красоты, на мой взгляд. Вот код:

```
function get_non_zero( $str_keys, $data ) {
    $keys = explode( ',', $str_keys );
    foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
        if ( ! empty( $data[ $key ] ) ) {
            return $data[ $key ];
        }
    }

    return null;
}

$data = ['key0' => 0, 'key1' => 1, 'key3'=> 3];
echo( get_non_zero( 'key1,key2', $data ) ); // выведет 1
```

Может быть, у кого-то есть идеи, как это реализовать более понятно и красиво, возможно, вообще без функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если пишите для себя, то можно так:

```
$data = ["key0" => 0, "key1" => 1, "key3"=> 3];

$search = array_flip(explode(",", "key1,key2"));
$result = array_intersect_key($data, $search);

echo count($result) > 1 ? null : array_pop($result);
```

Если с кодом будут работать и другие, тогда лучше в функцию, с комментариями и красивым ветвлением.

```
function getNonZero($keys, $data)
{
    $search = array_flip(explode(",", $keys));
    $result = array_intersect_key($data, $search);

    if (count($result) > 1):
        return null;
    else:
        return array_pop($result);
    endif;
}

$data = ["key0" => 0, "key1" => 1, "key3"=> 3];
$search = "key1,key2";

echo getNonZero($search, $data);
```

**"Сверх максимум"**:

```
function searchInArray($value)
{
    preg_match("([\w+]{1,})", $value, $matches);
    return !empty($matches) ? $matches[0] : $value;
}

function getNonZero($search, $data)
{
    $search = array_map("searchInArray", explode(",", $search));
    $result = array_intersect_key($data, array_flip($search));

    if (count($result) === 1):
        return is_array($result) ? array_shift($result[key($result)]) : $result;
    else:
        return null;
    endif;
}

$data = ['key0' => 0, 'fields' => ['name_1'=>1], 'key3'=> 3];
$sting = 'name,entry.436917433,billing_first_name,fields[name_1]';

echo getNonZero($sting, $data);
```

Comment: Отлично! Единственное что, нужно еще чтобы если элементов было больше одного найдено, вернуть ошибку в том или ином виде, а не просто последний найденный элемент массива. Но это мелочи, на самом деле.

Comment: Этот код, насколько я вижу, Вернет в случае элементов более одного, просто `null`, и это в целом вариант, просто уточнил.

Comment: Ну и  последнее - жаль, что не выполняется задача сверх максимума, когда очередным ключом может быть что-то вроде `fielfds[name1]`, что будет обозначать, что есть вложенный элемент массива.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko а пример входных данные c fielfds[name1] и массива для поиска можно? :)

Comment: Строка с ключами: `'name,entry.436917433,billing_first_name,fields[name_1]'`

Comment: Массив: `$data = ['key0' => 0, 'fields' => ['name_1'=>1], 'key3'=> 3];`

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko добавил "сверх максимум", проверяйте! ;)

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/O9W-xo3Z3LTdxu

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko попробуйте убрать типизацию у аргументов функции getNonZero. :)

Comment: Да, я на самом деле уже сам сделал аналогично, правда у вас не учитывается, что есть еще условие "а если подойдут несколько ключей, выдать ошибку." Но это уже на самом деле можно без проблем самому сделать. Фишка в том, что я уже наткнулся на очередное усложнение в задаче, может быть вложенность свыше одного уровня. Так как этого не было в задании, ваше считаю правильным (а главное - красивым), так что отмечаю его верным :) Свое решение, если интересно, выложу чуть позже.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko ну условия вроде "а если", могут расти бесконечно. :-D Да и философия стэка дать ответ или подвести к решению, а не решить всё за автора. Тогда бы люди сюда ТЗ сразу выкладывали. :) Ваше решение выкладывайте обязательно! С интересом гляну!

Comment: Само собой что "а если" я не учитываю, это так, объяснение к тому, почему я свой вариант еще выложу :)

Comment: Добавил и свой вариант.

Answer (score 1):

В общем-то, достаточно элегантный вариант решения самой сложной задачи предложил в предыдущем ответе @socode, но после у меня возникла задача обрабатывать не только приведенные варианты в посте, типа `fields[name_1]`, но и с большим количеством уровней вложенности. В этом случае, на мой взгляд, обязательно понадобится рекурсия, и можно равно как переписать вариант в другом ответе под это дело, так и написать другой:

```
function preg_req( $key, &$keys = array() ) {
    preg_match( '/(.*)\[(.*)\]/', $key, $matches );
    if ( count( $matches ) ) {
        $keys[] = $matches[2];
        preg_req( $matches[1], $keys );
    } else {
        $keys[] = $key;

        return $keys;
    }
}

function get_non_zero( $str_keys, $data ) {
    $keys = explode( ',', $str_keys );
    foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
        $matched_keys = array();
        preg_req( $key, $matched_keys );
        $val = array_reduce( array_reverse($matched_keys), function ( $data, $key ) {
            return isset( $data[ $key ] ) ? $data[ $key ] : null;
        }, $data );
        if ( ! empty( $val ) ) {
            return $val;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

$data['fields']['name_1'] = 'asdasd';
$data['fields']['1588698_1']['3762726'] = 'asdasd';

echo get_non_zero( 'name,billing,fields[name_1]', $data );
echo get_non_zero( 'phone,entry.3221,fields[1588698_1][3762726]', $data );
```